# Connect Google domain to Google Cloud Bucket

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I'm trying to get my Google domain to connect to my Google Cloud bucket. I have followed all the instructions carefully on this page:

https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/hosting-static-website

...such as entering the DNS numbers, making the files public, etc. And the domain is verified since it is a Google domain. But no matter what I do, I can't get the domain to serve up the files in the bucket. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/hosting-static-website-http

Answer (score 15):

Create a **CNAME alias that points to c.storage.googleapis.com.** is where google cloud documentation does not give much information.

Follow this steps. I will take an example of www.mydomain.com as a sample domain.

1. Goto https://domains.google.com
2. Select Configure DNS.
3. Goto Custom Resource Records section at the bottom
4. Put **www.mydomain.com(your domain)** in the left input box.
5. Select **CNAME** in the drop down. **c.storage.googleapis.com** as DATA. Hit save. The name would come as www. Dont worry about that.
6. Goto Storage of google cloud. Create a **new bucket**. Give the bucket name same as the domain name ie **www.mydomain.com** here.
7. Upload the files in the bucket.
8. Go inside the bucket and give permission to the pages as share publicly (https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/making-data-public#buckets).
9. Goto website configuration(3 dots towards the right) in the bucket list. Give the name of the home page to **Main Page**. For example index.html. Put the error page in the 404 not found input box. Hit save and you are done.
10. Try running your website and see if you are able to hit the page.

If you are getting error as DNS not found then there is some issue with CNAME linking.

If you are geting error from the bucket such as permission that means that your DNS is connected to bucket but there are some permission issues with the files.

Comment: Google has made a little change on how you make your website files (as well as the whole website) public. Hence the "Point 8" has to be done a bit differently. 

Here is the easy to follow guide from Google: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/making-data-public#buckets

Nice instruction anyway :)

Comment: can we deploy website on root domain means without www?
If yes then how?

Answer (score 3):

When doing anything with DNS, it's important to remember that DNS propagation can take an hour or more.

Here are some quick troubleshooting steps:

1. Were you able to create a bucket named www.mywebsite.com? If so, you have definitely already demonstrated to Google that you own the domain.
2. Use a DNS tool like dig or any number of lookup websites to verify that the domain 'wwww.mywebsite.com' has a CNAME entry with the value 'c.storage.googleapis.com'. If that's not true, Google will never see requests for your domain.
3. Verify that your files are publicly visible.
4. Verify that you configured a main page suffix, so that GCS knows which file to serve if the user goes to "htp://www.mywebsite.com". You can do this by running: `gsutil web set -m index.html gs://www.mywebsite.com`.
5. Make sure you're going to http://www.mywebsite.com and not https://www.mywebsite.com. GCS does not directly support HTTPS for custom domain web serving. To do that, you'll want to configure Google Cloud Load  Balancing: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/http/using-http-lb-with-cloud-storage
6. Are you trying to set up a root domain, like "mywebsite.com.", and not a subdomain, like "www.mywebsite.com."? You can't do that. Root domains shouldn't have CNAME resource records.

Comment: When I set up the settings in Google domains, it told me to make the CNAME setting ghs.googlehosted.com, not the googleapis thing you mentioned. I will try it though, and thanks for the help.

Comment: the place that told me to use that CNAME setting was AppEngine-->Settings-->Custom Domains

Comment: Ah, ghs.googlehosted.com is for setting up G Suites. Serving static content through GCS is a very different pathway.

Comment: perhaps the googleapis thing is for people who have their domian registered with another company, but my registrar is Google Domains

Comment: I just want to host a simple static website, so I don't think I need G Suites. But I'm not sure.

Comment: OK, I was successful in connecting the www. subdomain to a bucket that starts with www. But I can't connect my root domain name to it, only the www subdomain. For the www subdomain, I set the CNAME setting to the googleapis thing. Any help on connecting the root domain would be appreciated.

Comment: Sorry, that's an unfortunate limitation of DNS. Setting a CNAME on a root domain is generally disallowed and/or highly discouraged.

Comment: I finally figured it out. I made the bucket with the www prefix, put a CNAME setting that points to the googleapis thing, and then under synthetic records, I put a permanent forward from the root domain to the www domain name using the @ character. Now everything works. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

I finally figured it out. I made the bucket with the www prefix, put a CNAME setting that points to the googleapis thing, and then under synthetic records, I put a permanent forward from the root domain to the www domain name using the @ character. Now everything works. Thanks for your help.